# force jQuery to load in the head

Tags: plugins, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, headers

I've written a plugin which uses `wp_enqueue_script("jquery");` to load jQuery. I need to load jQuery in the head and not at the bottom of the body. However, I think that this command is overwritten by some theme which loads jQuery at the bottom of the body so preventing my plugin to work properly. How can I force WP to load jQuery in the head?

Comment: if the location of jquery prevents your plugin from working, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: +1 for Milo's comment. To expand on it: I can only speak for myself, but I'd consider it bad practice of a plugin author to force my WP to load jQuery in the `<head>`. I would venture to guess, that you simply enqueue your own scripts too early, read up on [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and make them dependent on `'jquery'`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: new solution, based on one of the comments.  If you are using [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load your js file, make sure `jQuery` is a dependency so that it gets called before your code:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', 'my-script.js', array( 'jquery'), $ver, true );
```

You can then remove the original enqueue call you had since `jQuery` will be included automagically

Comment: Apart that your command is a syntax error according to the page you cite, if my script fails because jQuery is not loaded, how can it not fail calling jQuery(...) as you suggest? Anyway, it does not work.

Comment: just updated.  There are a couple ways of doing it

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. And indeed I continue to not understand why `jQuery( document ).ready( function($){` should work when `jQuery(function (){` fails. If jQuery is NOT loaded yet, any call to jQuery fails. Isn't it?

Comment: The WordPress-bundled jQuery library is configured in **no-conflict** mode.

Comment: Try to use: var jq = jQuery || $.noConflict()